# Can a MapReduce job in Oozie read from a file?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

When creating a workflow in Oozie, I have a first java step that generates a file with the list of files I need for the next step (a map-reduce). How can I feed that map-reduce job with that file?

I know that I could tick the *Capture output* box of the java step and then use *mapred.input.dir* in the map-reduce step to use that captured output as an input. But I want to detach myself from that.

Just for the record, the content of my file looks like:

> /data/kafka/4/camus/DATA.TRADE.ORDERHISTORY/daily/2015/07/18,/data/kafka/4/camus/DATA.TRADE.ORDERHISTORY/daily/2015/07/19,/data/kafka/4/camus/DATA.TRADE.ORDERHISTORY/daily/2015/07/20,/data/kafka/4/camus/DATA.TRADE.ORDERHISTORY/daily/2015/07/21,/data/kafka/4/camus/DATA.TRADE.ORDERHISTORY/daily/2015/07/22,/data/kafka/4/camus/DATA.TRADE.ORDERHISTORY/daily/2015/07/23,/data/kafka/4/camus/DATA.TRADE.ORDERHISTORY/daily/2015/07/24,/data/kafka/4/camus/DATA.TRADE.ORDERHISTORY/daily/2015/07/25,/data/kafka/4/camus/DATA.TRADE.ORDERHISTORY/daily/2015/07/26,/data/kafka/4/camus/DATA.TRADE.ORDERHISTORY/daily/2015/07/27,/data/kafka/4/camus/DATA.TRADE.ORDERHISTORY/daily/2015/07/28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to use that file as an *input file* or a *parameter file*??

In the second case,

- activate **<capture-output/>** option for the initial Action
- output something like "param.file=/a/b/c/z.txt"
- in the next Action, use the appropriate EL function to retrieve the
  file name and pass it as a **<property>** or **<env>**

  *${wf:actionData("InitialActionName")["param.file"]}*
- then use a few lines of Java to open that HDFS file and do whatever
  you are supposed to do with the content, before doing the actual Map
  or Reduce work

Comment: That's pretty much what I was looking for. What's the other option about?